# Transaction not mined but block number created

Tags: transactions, mining, private-blockchain, pending-transactions

When I send a transaction it generates hash number but the transaction index number not increased as per below. Can someone care to explain?

```
eth.getTransaction("0x46542d25d044f73cff4c19081284ac84623de6bcaceb1aadd0545d21cd44a056")
{
  blockHash: "0x71d79df1f93332f4cf3b239231a487ec61f4f0385447520078e51c56913fa091",
  blockNumber: 2,
  from: "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d",
  gas: 4700000,
  gasPrice: 0,
  hash: "0x46542d25d044f73cff4c19081284ac84623de6bcaceb1aadd0545d21cd44a056",
  input: "0x4a78245865ad5c90515ab305fbdb5959abd40a8fba263eb4a30497a4c354b9a77a649c11d3e2f8cd305468fcfef474c001b7d7d5fa3fa7f482a64a3513cc5923",
  nonce: 1,
  r: "0x47e083e2d701c89eb0919733fde0163d5bdf878e46f8aa0bee300214d00b6cfd",
  s: "0x2a60267c3f549437a0fb7f474f5e00d9a2afa019cfb5b9a800875948cf14e4d7",
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x25",
  value: 0
}
```

Comment: Give more background about how you are running the blockchain (what client: ganache, geth, parity, ..) how you broadcasted the transaction, how do you know it was not mined.

Answer (score 1):

TransactionIndex is the position of the transaction within the block it was mined in. It is not a global index.

For example if you have transactions T1, T2 in block 1; transactions T3, T4, T5 in block 2 and T6 in block 3.

- T1 have transactionIndex 0 in block 1, T2 have transactionIndex 1 in block 1.
- T3 have transactionIndex 0 in block 2, .. T5 have transactionIndex 2 in block 2.
- T6 have transactionIndex 0 in block 3

Answer (score 0):

Having `blockNumber` and `blockHash` in the response means that the transaction was mined and included in in that specific block

Having `to` null means your transaction tried to create a contract

Is it possible that your transaction created an error and that's why you think it wasn't mined?

What does the receipt look like? Try running

```
eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x46542d25d044f73cff4c19081284ac84623de6bcaceb1aadd0545d21cd44a056")
```

Comment: eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x46542d25d044f73cff4c19081284ac84623de6bcaceb1aadd0545d21cd44a056")
{
  blockHash: "0x71d79df1f93332f4cf3b239231a487ec61f4f0385447520078e51c56913fa091",
  blockNumber: 2,
  contractAddress: "0x1349f3e1b8d71effb47b840594ff27da7e603d17",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 0,
  from: "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d",
  gasUsed: 0,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x0",
  root: "0x7776acd97aa1631c6df28a9572bd9bb6a861b13ac61dc0b30cbfea529529b11c",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "hash value",
  transactionIndex: 0
}